# Passing data between PHP pages

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My index.php is:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Example Ajax PHP Form</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <form id="my_form_id">
            Your Email Address: <input type="text" id="email" /><br>
            <button type="submit" id="ddd">button</button>
        </form>
        
        
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#my_form_id').submit(function(e){               
                    var email = $('#email').val();
                    console.log(email);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'http://localhost/script.php',
                        data: {email: email},
                        success: function(data){
                          alert(data);  
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

My goal is to pass an email from my index.php page to another file titled script.php. The script.php code is:

```
<?php 
$emailAddress = '';
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    
    echo $_POST['email'];
    $emailAddress = $_POST['email'];
}


echo 'Received email was: ' .$emailAddress;
?>
```

When I run my index.php page I am able to enter an email address and the data is successfully displayed in an alert box. However, when I refresh the script.php page it doesn't display the email address. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The PHP flow is incorrect. If you want to display the email on screen at the `script.php`, you shouldn't use AJAX POST requests.

Comment: @Raptor thank you for the input. What would you suggest I do?

Comment: I suggest to edit the question title. I think the issue is not passing the data between scripts. As you say it works. The issue comes when you refresh and it does not display the previously sent data.

Comment: THank you I will edit. Do you have any solutions for this?

Comment: Check the first answer related with storage. If you don't want storage then don't use ajax and 2 scripts. Pass the data to the script itself (not to other page). Perhaps I'm missing the point.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to keep the value between page refresh unless you use some storage method: file, database or session.

In case you are using some of this, in index.php the first thing to do is retrieved the stored email and set it as the value of the input.

Simple pseudocode:

```
If there is email stored 
    Set email as input value

Show form
```

Check https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php for more info in PHP sessions

---- EDIT with session storage:

at the beggining of index.php add:

```
<?php

session_start();
$emailAddress = isset($_SESSION['email']) ? $_SESSION['email']:'';

?>
```

and the input definition now is:

```
Your Email Address: <input type="text" id="email"  value="<?= $emailAddress ?>"/><br>
```

And script.php have to be like:

```
<?php

session_start();

$emailAddress = '';
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    echo $_POST['email'];
    $emailAddress = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $emailAddress;
} else {
    unset($_SESSION['email']);
}

echo 'Received email was: ' . $emailAddress;
```

Comment: It is incorrect. You can still pass the value from script A to B via GET / POST requests, though POST requests are the correct way to do. The true problem of the OP is that it uses AJAX POST request, but fails to obtain the email value and display on screen. p.s. please suggest better tutorial sites, such as php.net.

Comment: Yes. But not when refreshing. The issue is not pass the data between scripts, but to keep it after refresh as I understand from the last paragraph on the question. Good suggestion on the reference!

Comment: Edited the question with example code using session storage.

Comment: Using session is also a viable way. However, it depends on how does the email display. If the `script.php` is called via AJAX POST, its response won't get displayed on screen; it only appears in Developer Console's network panel. jQuery's AJAX POST expects a JSON response by default. Alternatively, if the `<input>` has no `name` attribute, the `$_POST['email']` will not be set if the form is directly submitted via form post instead of an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$e = array();
$e['error'] = 'not ok';
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    //echo $_POST['email'];
    //$emailAddress = $_POST['email'];
    $e['emailAdress'] = $_POST['email'];
    $e['text'] = 'Received email was: ';
    $e['error'] = 'ok';
}
echo json_encode($e);
?>
```

Use the **json_encode** method in your php script

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#my_form_id').submit(function(e){               
                    var email = $('#email').val();
                    console.log(email);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'http://localhost/script.php',
                        data: {email: email},
                        success: function(data){
                          alert(data.error);
                          //do stuff
                        }
                    },"json");
                });
            });
        </script>
```

And it is your index.php script that will receive the data.
It is Ajax which and made to work on a single page!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the email in the next page (i.e. `script.php`), you can use the following codes:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="script.php">
<p>Your Email Address: <input type="email" name="email" required /><br />
<button>Send</button></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Example - script.php</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    echo 'Received email was: ' . $_POST['email'];
} else {
    echo 'No email is received. Something went wrong.';
}
?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Alternatively, if you insist using AJAX to pass the data and display on screen, you can do the followings:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Example</title>
<style>
#result { display: none; }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Your Email Address: <input type="email" name="email" id="txt_email" required /><br />
<button type="button" id="btn_send">Send</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
$('#btn_send').click(function(){
    $.post('script.php', {
        email: $('#txt_email').val()
    }, function(data) {
        if(data.status == 'error') {
            console.log('Error occurred');
        } else if(data.status == 'success') {
            $('#result').html('Email is ' + data.email).show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']); // TODO: validate email via filter_var()
    echo json_encode(array('email' => $email, 'status' => 'success'));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error'));
}
?>
```